# combine metrics/results into a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code and I wanted to take all the metrics and scores alongside the model and combine it into a dataframe. The code below is just one example, I have 9 other models that I want to combine to have a dataframe which contains the 10 models and their scores/metrics and the execution time

```
# Multi-layer Perceptron Regression

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

start = time.time()

diamonds_mlp = MLPRegressor()
diamonds_mlp.fit(X_train , y_train)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = diamonds_mlp, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10)
y_pred = diamonds_mlp.predict(X_test)

end = time.time()

print('')
print('---Multi-Layer Perceptron Regression---')
print('Score : %.2f' % diamonds_mlp.score(X_test, y_test))
print(accuracies)

mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
rmse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)**0.5
r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)

print('')
print('MSE    : %0.2f ' % mse)
print('MAE    : %0.2f ' % mae)
print('RMSE   : %0.2f ' % rmse)
print('R2     : %0.2f ' % r2)
print(f"Runtime of the program is {end - start}")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a series, which we will make the rows of the dataframe, like this:

```
s = pd.Series({'Model': 'MLPRegressor', 
               'MSE': mse, 
               'MAE': mae,
               'RMSE': rmse,
               'R2' :r2,
               'Runtime': end-start})
```

If you have a long script with a chunk of code like what you posted for each model (or are iterating through them), I would initialize an empty list at the very beginning like `list_of_rows = []`, and then after each test, add the series with your metric to the list with `list_of_rows.append(s)`. Then after you've done all the tests, you can build a dataframe with `df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_rows)`.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for that! It kinda makes sense, im not sure how to format this though for each of mu chunks, kinda new to python

Comment: Do you have one big long script that does all the models, or do you have a separate python file for each one?

Comment: Thank you that worked for me.